# How to render html from a external js file

Tags: javascript

This might be a dumb question but I have actually never done this and what I am trying is not working.

I have 2 files

```
test.html
test.js
```

I am linking the js as an external in test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In my js file I have something like this

```
document.appendChild('<div>testing</div>')
```

I also tried

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body').appendChild('<div>testing</div>')
```

What I am doing wrong? I just want to learn how to generate html from an external js file for a future project I am working on.

Answer (score 4):

You should generally try to run scripts that depend on the page *after* the document has been parsed, not before - if you put the script in `<head>` and run it immediately, the `<body>` has not been created yet. Give your script tag the `defer` attribute so that it only runs after the document is fully parsed:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

- `appendChild` accepts an *element* as a parameter, not a string
- You need to append to the `body`, not the `document` itself (`Only one element on document allowed.`)
- If you want to append an HTML string, assign/concatenate to the `.innerHTML` property
- Assigning to `.innerHTML` will corrupt existing references to elements inside, including listeners. In order to keep listeners active, use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead:

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
  .textContent = 'testing1';
  
// Another method:

document.body.innerHTML += '<div>testing2</div>';

// Another method:

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>testing3</div>');
```

Comment: So weird because it generates nothing for me

Comment: Ok so when I put the external call after `</body>` it works and not in the head. Why is that?

Comment: See edit - document hasn't been loaded yet since the script is *above* the `<body>`. You can also keep the script in the `head` and give it the `defer` attribute